# Does Virtualbox from Oracle have similar tool like Vmware vSphere Client?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-vsphere

I'm using VirtualBox on my Windows 7 personal PC for open-source OS environment testing.

Today, a friend show me his Vmware vSphere Client where he can manage the same `Virtualbox` thing but under server-client manner.

I just think it would be lovely if there's a such similar tool to work with Virtualbox - multiple user share the same set of `virtual machines`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMWare vSphere Client is for managing VM Nodes (virtual-machines) using VMWare ESXi and variants. You can not compare VMWare vSphere Client or VMWare ESXi to Oracle's VirtualBox.

You can compare VMWare Workstation with Oracle VirtualBox.

Comment: I'm newbie to virualization technology. Thanks for updating my knowledge

Comment: What is Oracle's product should I compare with VMWare ESXi?

Comment: Oracle has none I guess to compare with. But VMWare ESXi has some alternates you can find in xen virtualization which is open source product from Citrix.